# iOS 8 Swift Read Plist

Tags: ios, swift, plist

I want to read values from a plist file as integers.  I have the following code:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("savedState", ofType: "plist")
let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)
let players: AnyObject = String(dict.valueForKey("players") as NSString)
let level: AnyObject = String(dict.valueForKey("level") as NSString)
let numPlayers = Int(players as NSNumber)
let playLevel = Int(level as NSNumber)
```

The let players: and let level: crash my app.  I know this should be simple - I just can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Your use of the plural "players" leads me to suspect that there is more than one player in your plist. If so then you probably have an array of dictionaries. Giving the details of your crash -line and message would help

Comment: it would be much more helpful if you show us the content of `.plist` file too, because this snippet makes no sense without the model.

Comment: The error is EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_i386_BPT,subdued=0x0).  It's a single dictionary with a single key called players.  numberOfPlayers would probably be a better key name.

Comment: Here's my plist:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>players</key>
 <integer>2</integer>
 <key>level</key>
 <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
</plist>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may be looking for something like this:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("savedState", ofType: "plist")
let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)
let players = dict.valueForKey("players") as? String
let level = dict.valueForKey("level") as? String
let numPlayers = players != nil ? players!.toInt() : 0
let playLevel = level != nil ? level!.toInt() : 0
```

It attempts to read players and level from the plist as optional strings, then if they are non nil it sets numPlayers and playLevel to their Int value. If they are nil numPlayers and playLevel are set to 0. Although if your plist values are integers, why not just read them as Ints?

```
let players = dict.valueForKey("players") as? Int
let level = dict.valueForKey("level") as? Int
```