# Can't get plist URL in Swift

Tags: swift, plist

I'm really confused on this one. There are dozens of questions around the web asking "How do I get info from my plist file in Swift?" and the same answer is posted everywhere:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Config", ofType: "plist")
```

However, this line produces always produces `nil` for me. I have replaced `Config` with other components found in the default plist file, but get `nil` as well.

I am trying to access my custom `ProductIdentifiers` Array like so:

```
let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("ProductIdentifiers", withExtension: "plist")!
var productArray = NSArray(contentsOfURL: url) as! [[String:AnyObject!]]
```

I get a crash stating `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` on productArray. I have also tried this with other default plist values in place of `ProductIdentifiers`.

Does anyone know why this is not working for me even though there are so many posts around of people using this successfully?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never heard of the OP's approach working before. Instead, you should open the `Info.plist` file itself, then extract values from it, like so:

## Swift 3.0+

```
func getInfoDictionary() -> [String: AnyObject]? {
    guard let infoDictPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Info", ofType: "plist") else { return nil }
    return NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: infoDictPath) as? [String : AnyObject]
}

let productIdentifiers = getInfoDictionary()?["ProductIdentifiers"]
```

## Swift 2.0

```
func getInfoDictionary() -> NSDictionary? {
    guard let infoDictPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Info", ofType: "plist") else { return nil }
    return NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: infoDictPath)
}

let productIdentifiers = getInfoDictionary()?["ProductIdentifiers"]
```

Comment: Here's a few I've tried: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045570/swift-read-plist, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26391883/ios-8-swift-read-plist. Your way worked perfectly first try though!

Answer (score 1):

`Resource` represents the **file name** of the plist rather than its contents.

The root object of the plist is probably a dictionary.

Replace `MyPlist` with the real file name.
This code prints the contents of the plist

```
if let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("MyPlist", withExtension: "plist"), 
       root = NSDictionary(contentsOfURL: url) as? [String:AnyObject] 
{
     print(root)
} else {
    print("Either the file does not exist or the root object is an array")
}
```