# Load Url image from Plist in Swift

Tags: swift, url, plist

I have a plist running in my project which contains number of image urls.I am trying to pass the url image to my imageView which is in the same viewController.I found similar questions from github like [Loading/Downloading image from URL on Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231680/loading-downloading-image-from-url-on-swift) , [Swift - Read plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045570/swift-read-plist) , [Can't get plist URL in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35118301/cant-get-plist-url-in-swift) I went through all those answers but no luck so far rather than fatal crash. My partial codes as follows....

**Method 1:**

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "apps", ofType: "plist"), 
        let root = (NSArray(contentsOfFile: path))
    {
        let url = NSURL(string: path)
        let data = NSData(contentsOf: url! as URL)
        if let imageData = data {   
        imageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data) 
    }

      **// Swift Console Printinging as Follows**

        print(root) 
        // printing all my plist url links like   {icon = "https://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/image/girl_face_freckles_eyes_92358_1920x1080.jpg";}

        print(url)
        // (/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/52DA3F73-83E0-4C29-9DE1-D8D5F0731C13/data/Containers/Bundle/Applica ... ps.plist)

        print(data)
        // nil

        print(imageView.image)
        //nil
    } else {
        print("Either the file does not exist or the root object is an array")
    }
```

Method 2:

```
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "apps", ofType: "plist")
    let url = NSURL(string: path!)
    let imgData = try? Data(contentsOf: url as! URL)
    let img = UIImage(data: imgData!)!

    print(img) // fatal crash

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`path` is the path to your plist, not to your image URL.

The image URL is in the key "icon" in the "root" array.

Get the first item of the array and subscript with the key, you should get your image URL:

```
if let item = root[0] as? [String:Any] {
    if let result = item["icon"] as? String {
        print(result)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `path` in `(NS)Bundle` is a file system path and these paths **must** be created with  `URL(fileURLWithPath:)`

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "apps", ofType: "plist")
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
```

But why does nobody use the URL related API which is much more convenient

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "apps", withExtension: "plist")
```